# Update one table based on values in another table using case statement (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the below query to update a table based on values in another table using case statement. And i get the following error.

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from tbl_a as a, tbl_b as b
  WHERE a.DIV_NO = b.' at line 12
```

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE a
  SET
    a.MIN_5 = b.Min_Five,
    a.IN_PR = b.Ad_Flag ,
    a.FRC = (
                    CASE
                       WHEN b.Prc_Fl = 'N' THEN 'Y'
                       WHEN b.Prc_Fl = 'Y' THEN 'N'
                       ELSE 'D'
                    END
            )
  FROM tbl_a AS a, tbl_b AS b
  WHERE a.DIV_NO = b.Div_num
    AND a.OFR_ID = b.Flg ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `JOIN`

```
UPDATE 
  tbl_a AS a
  JOIN   
  tbl_b AS b ON (a.DIV_NO = b.Div_num AND  a.OFR_ID = b.Flg) 
  SET
  a.MIN_5 = b.Min_Five,
  a.IN_PR = b.Ad_Flag,
  a.FRC = 
    CASE
      WHEN b.Prc_Fl = 'N' 
      THEN 'Y' 
      WHEN b.Prc_Fl = 'Y' 
      THEN 'N' 
      ELSE 'D' 
    END
```

Comment: Your problem is not the CASE statement, it is the specifying of the FROM;  You can remove the CASE statement and still get same error.

Comment: Yeah , you are right mhoglan. I was getting that error even without case statement. I tried the join as well but i did it after the set command and not before which was again showing a syntax error. Anyways, thank you both for helping me.